# How to change route without fetching in child component Next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, routes, next.js

I have one page with Aside component and Main component for showing content.

[image]

At first aside fetches data to show links. But every time when I change route clicking on aside links, aside fetches data again, how to prevent it?

Comment: Can you attach code for the Router and Aside components?

Comment: @pyroCoder, it is not about a code, I need the logical explanation

Comment: why not to check if the data exists, if so, don't fetch.

Comment: @felixmosh, yeah, I know it, but how to check?

Comment: Share the code where you fetch the data...